# uniq -c for counting duplicate lines in a file not working

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I have a file called test.txt which contains the following text.

```
red: 8-17-20
red: 8-17-20
red: 8-18-20
blue: 8-18-20
blue: 8-18-20
blue: 8-18-20
red: 8-18-20
red: 8-18-20
red: 8-19-20
red: 8-19-20
blue: 8-19-20
red: 8-19-20
blue: 8-19-20
blue: 8-19-20
blue: 8-18-20
```

I've read on plenty of possible answers on how to count the duplicate lines and majority of them points me to use `uniq -c`

I have used the following command `sort test.txt | uniq -c` and the results I'm getting is this

```
      4 blue: 8-18-20
      3 blue: 8-19-20
      2 red: 8-17-20
      3 red: 8-18-20
      3 red: 8-19-20
```

why don't I see

```
      2 red: 8-17-20
      3 red: 8-18-20
      3 blue: 8-18-20
      3 red: 8-19-20
      4 blue: 8-19-20
```

Can someone help me understand what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect uniq to take the sorted input and print out in an unsorted order?

Comment: It is working as expected because it is sorting also the lines (alphabetically ascending) and `blue` is before `red`.  `uniq` needs sorted input. If you want to keep the file order, and do not sort, you have to use other solution, e.g. with `awk`

Comment: I have another file with 3 lines, apple, orange apple. when i run the code im getting 1 apple, 1 apple 1 orange. when i should be getting 2 apple 1 orange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sorting on the way in, but you also want to sort on the way out.

```
$ sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -n
      2 red: 8-17-20
      3 blue: 8-19-20
      3 red: 8-18-20
      3 red: 8-19-20
      4 blue: 8-18-20
```

Note that `3 blue` sorts before `3 red`.

Comment: It still does not give me the desired ouput. Lets say I have a file that has  5 lines. orange, apple apple banana and orange. (one on each line) when i run the sort |uniq | sort.. it gives me 1 banana, 1 orange, 1 orange, 2 apple.  not sure why its not giving me 1 banana 2 apple, 2 orange.

Comment: @Vineeth I can't reproduce that behaviour. Check for trailing whitespace.